# Oracle select most recent date record

Tags: oracle

I am trying to find the most recent record based on a date field.  When I set latest = 1 in the where clause, I get an error.  Please help if possible. DATE is a the field I'm sorting by. I have tried both latest = 1 and latest = '1'

```
SELECT 
STAFF_ID,
SITE_ID,
PAY_LEVEL,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STAFF_ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) latest

 FROM OWNER.TABLE
WHERE   END_ENROLLMENT_DATE is null 
AND latest = 1
```

Comment: ...and you probably don't want the latest record, but the latest record: date <= SYSDATE (avoid future dated records, say for the planned salary increase next month...)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you can't use aliases from select list inside the WHERE clause (because of the **[Order of Evaluation](http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/sql/node22.html) of a SELECT statement**)

also you cannot use `OVER` clause inside WHERE clause - "You can specify analytic functions with this clause in the select list or ORDER BY clause." (citation from **[docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i97476)**)

```
select *
from (select
  staff_id, site_id, pay_level, date, 
  max(date) over (partition by staff_id) max_date
  from owner.table
  where end_enrollment_date is null
)
where date = max_date
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming staff_id + date form a uk, this is another method:

```
SELECT STAFF_ID, SITE_ID, PAY_LEVEL
  FROM TABLE t
  WHERE END_ENROLLMENT_DATE is null
    AND DATE = (SELECT MAX(DATE)
                  FROM TABLE
                  WHERE staff_id = t.staff_id
                    AND DATE <= SYSDATE)
```

Answer (score 4):

i think i'd try with MAX something like this:

```
SELECT staff_id, max( date ) from owner.table group by staff_id
```

then link in your other columns:

```
select staff_id, site_id, pay_level, latest
from owner.table, 
(   SELECT staff_id, max( date ) latest from owner.table group by staff_id ) m
where m.staff_id = staff_id
and m.latest = date
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select *
from (select
  staff_id, site_id, pay_level, date, 
  rank() over (partition by staff_id order by date desc) r
  from owner.table
  where end_enrollment_date is null
)
where r = 1
```

Comment: The ranking helped a lot, thanks, as I had to join to multiple tables and didn't want to have to repeat those joins in a sub-select.

Comment: Distinction between rank and row_number. I have a case where I have duplicates in the subset I'm partitioning on, rank gives me multiple 1's in that case, row_number breaks the tie