# SQL query for latest record

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to select the latest record from a table as based on a date field (crtn_dt). The query below does not work. Does anyone have an idea how it should be fixed?

```
 select * from parcels
 order by crtn_dt desc
 where rownum = 1
```

Comment: the answer here may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128194/oracle-select-most-recent-date-record

Comment: well syntax is wrong on your query.  where comes after from before order by. but then it still will not produce desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to order data in the subquery and filter them in an outer query.

```
select *
  from (
        select * 
          from parcels
         order by crtn_dt desc
       )
 where rownum = 1
```

`order by` clause is among last operations to perform. 
What your query does, apart from being semantically incorrect, it returns one (thanks to `rownum = 1` predicate) arbitrary row, and then applies `order by` clause to that one row.